# Display saved PDF file from database to PDFVIEWER

Tags: mysql, vb.net, pdf

I have successfully saved a pdf file to my database (MySQL) as a longblob and used this code :

```
opf.Filter = "PDF FILES |*.pdf"
    If opf.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

         //Display the PDF you want to save in the PDFVIEWER
        pdfview.src = opf.FileName

        Dim Mystream As New FileStream(opf.FileName, FileMode.Open)
        Dim filesize As Long = Mystream.Length
        Dim buffer(filesize) As Byte
        Mystream.Read(buffer, 0, filesize)

         //Save the pdf file to the database
        Dim query As String = "insert into sample(pdfnaho)values(@file)"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", buffer)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("SAVED!")
        con.Close()

    End If
```

Then I used this code for displaying but It doesn't work and I don't know what to do :

```
Dim query As String = "select * from sample where id = 1"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
    con.Open()
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        If dr.HasRows Then
            pdfview.src = dr.GetString("pdfnaho")
        End If
    End While
    con.Close()
```

How should I display my saved pdf file from database? Thank You

Comment: Since you converted it to an array of bytes to save it as BLOB why are you trying to read back a string?  Also, if `id` is the PKI, you dont need that `While dr.Read` loop since there can only be one

Comment: I know that i should'nt be reading it as a string when displaying but I just dont really know what to do. I want to display the PDF FILE from the database to my PDFVIEWER and I don't know what to do or how to code it. I've searched for several days and could only see c# codes and I've been trying to convert the code to vb but could'nt succeed.

Comment: Rather than searching for codes, consider doing some research on the DataReader.  See if there are *other* methods which return something more appropriate for what you need

Answer (score 0):

I can not put this as a comment because I don't have enough reputation.

What PDF viewer are you using?.  If it is the Adobe PDF Viewer I am almost sure (from previous research for another project) that you can not stream into it.

This is an example from my previous project, I modified it to fit yours, make sure to edit the query to fit your table and columns names.

You have to ran a query that return only the cell with the file in binary.

```
Dim query as String = "SELECT file_content FROM sample WHERE ID=1;"

Public Sub OpenPDF()

    If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath() & "\temp.file") = True Then
        pdfview.src = "blank.pdf"
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath() & "\temp.file")
    End If

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
    Dim Buffer As Byte()

    con.open()
    Buffer = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    con.close()

    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.StartupPath() & "\temp.file", Buffer)

    pdfview.src = Application.StartupPath() & "\temp.file"
End Sub
```

With this example, the code will check if there is an existing "temp.file" and delete it, then load nothing on the pdfviewer to clear whatever is displaying.

The the database connection, get the data, store it on a file then display it with the pdfviewer.